# How to separate text and image in WordPress using foundation zurb

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

I can't find a solution how to separate the text and images from the page/post (not featured image) and put them in two separate columns using foundation, I know how it works in static website however in WordPress.

is there a way to just get the text and image alone rather than the whole post.

I want them to be in this order.

```
<div class="large-9">
   texts here
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="large-3">
   image here
</div>
```

This is the template I have but its only html.

http://dmd-winchester.org.uk/digihub/

Comment: Do you want this separator for `post content` ????

Comment: Well its originally for the pages like the home page. I can only make it happen if I hard code the columns in the edit text. See the example http://dmd-winchester.org.uk/digihub/

Comment: You need to add filter hook to `the_content` with regex filter...

Comment: If you are just adding content and running foundation, you can use it just as a static site inside of a page or a post. So you will need to have in either case have a structure like .row>.large-9.columns+.large-3.columns . Note, in your example you are missing both a row and the columns in your classes which will cause unexpected behavior. Also, you might want to use the push pull classes if you are going to alternate images as in your example, so that they will be in a logical order on mobile.

Comment: Yeah I know I can make it static but that wasn't the idea but if its my website I don't mind doing it that way. So I was planning to make it dynamic, I found a solution however its not doing what I want to do like my example above.